# how TRUEPREDICATE differ from [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES]?

Tags: core-data

I am using [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES]]; to debug my code to by pass universal true predicate.
When I exicuting lldb command po [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES], it print TRUEPREDICATE.

The return type for predicateWithValue: is NSPredicate.

When I changed it to [fetchRequest setPredicate:TRUEPREDICATE]; Xcode complain a syntax error "use of un-declared identifier"

My question is should I have to import any header file to remove error? If not then how TRUEPREDICATE differ from [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES].

Comment: The correct syntax is `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"]`. It's the same as `[NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A universal true predicate can be created with

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];
```

or

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];
```

Both statements return the same predicate.

`po` prints the description of an object. The description of `NSPredicate` is similar to the format.

Comment: OMG! it was so simple but very hard to guess. I thought just TRUEPREDICATE will work like a literal.

Answer (score 4):

in **Swift 3** you would do as below

```
NSPredicate(value: true)
```

or

```
NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
```